# How to use iOS lock screen previous/next player buttons in Safari HTML5 player with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, html, safari

In Safari on iOS, when the <audio> DOM element is playing a sound file, you can pause/restart it via the device lock screen.

Question: Is there an event that I can listen for on that <audio> element that gets fired when the user clicks the next or previous buttons on that lock screen?

Bonus question: In Safari via HTML5 and Javascript, is there a way to show the audio file's meta data on that lock screen like you can with an app?

Comment: I have an HTML5 audio app that used to work OK when my iPhone went into lock screen but now neither the lock screen buttons work nor can it continue playing the list of tracks my JavaScript is coded to supply it. Any ideas?

Comment: @aproximation did you ever find a solution to this? I am most interested in displaying the meta data (artwork, title) on the lock screen

Answer (score 8):

I don't know the answer to your first question.

It is possible to show a song title (or other text) simply by adding an HTML title tag to your audio element.

`var player = getElementById('my_audio_element');
player.setAttribute('title', 'My Song Title');`

Unfortunately, it does not work to add an image in the same manner.

Comment: Hey SuprMan, thanks for this it works nicely when working with a DOM audio element. I'm using the Howlerjs library, which doesn't like the js audio object to any HTML elements, do you know how to set the title in this case?

Answer (score -1):

To add a title and a poster image you could do something like:

```
<video width="320" height="180" src="source.mp4" poster="poster.png">
```